# SELENIUM: element.text is slow and I don't know why

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

```
driver.get('https://nameberry.com/popular_names/US')
boys_names = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("""tr.even>.boys""")
girls_names = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("""tr.even>.girls""")
# so this goes quickly

def list_gen(ls): 
    hugo = []
    for i in ls:
        hugo.append(i.text)
    return hugo


i = time()
boys_names = list_gen(boys_names) # takes each <a> tag found before contained in boys_names and creates a list
# of names by taking everything CONTAINED (NOT attributes) between the opening and closing tag <a>
e = time()
print(e-i) # gives ~ 50 sec

i = time()
girls_names = list_gen(girls_names) # same thing but with girl names
e = time()
print(e-i) # gives ~ 80 sec 
# those timings are consistent even though no. of boys and girls is the same
# which is also weird
# no. is 1000 btw so that quite alot
```

So basically I'm confused as to why it takes so long. I came to the conclusion that the element.text is taking the most time for some reason. Is there a way to make this faster without importing other modules?

Comment: you can rewrite your `list_gen` function as a list comprehension:  `hugo = [i.text for i in ls]`  ... or you could name things a little better and do something like `texts = [element.text for element in elements]` .... although, it's kind of awesome that you name your list "hugo".

Comment: a list comprehension is the first thing I did but it didn't really help all that much ;/
'hugo' is like foo and bar. It doesn't really serve a greater purpose so it's just a random word

Comment: Try using `.get_attribute('innerText')` instead of `.text`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason your code is taking so long is because the loop in `list_gen` is sending a bunch of requests to the webpage as it's looping. If you set a breakpoint at your loop and look at the browser's network page in dev tools as it's running, you will see a slew of requests start with the loop. I think it's because the page is loading new elements as selenium scrolls down it. 
As far as I can tell, if you want it to be faster, you should use something else. My suggestion would be to use Beautiful soup.

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from time import time  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  

driver = webdriver.Chrome()  

i = time()  
driver.get('https://nameberry.com/popular_names/US')  
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html5lib')  

boys_names = [x.getText() for x in soup.find_all("td", {"class", "boys"})]  
girls_names = [x.getText() for x in soup.find_all("td", {"class", "girls"})]  

e = time()  
print(e - i) # gives ~ 14 sec for me
```

This gets the entire source of the webpage at once and parses it instead of having to work with the list of webdriver objects that the css selector return.

If you're not using the selenium browser for anything else and only want to get the names, you can use requests to get the page source even faster as you don't need to load the selenium browser.

```
import requests  

i = time()  

response = requests.get('https://nameberry.com/popular_names/US')  
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html5lib')  
boys_names = [x.getText() for x in soup.find_all("td", {"class", "boys"})]  
girls_names = [x.getText() for x in soup.find_all("td", {"class", "girls"})]  

e = time()  
print(e - i) # gives ~ 3.2 sec
```

Comment: great first answer!

Comment: Holy macaroni !!! I didn't know that this is how it works. I guess there isn't a way to just do this with selenium. Thanks for the thorough answer though. I appreciate the effort :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Javascript which will return the values in less than 2 seconds.

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr.even>.girls')).map(function(element) {return element.textContent;})
```

Just run that in our console, you will see the result.

Now you can call this Javascript in your python selenium script like

```
driver.execute_script("return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr.even>.girls')).map(function(element) {return element.textContent;})")
```

Try this out and let us know.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) The thing is - I am learning python and would prefer to stay python whenever possible. I appreciate the effort though

Comment: This is the answer for the actual question. This is how to get text quick.

Comment: YEs ! Super help !